# Does the given vector space form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is $\{1 + x, x + x^2, x^2 + x^3, x^3 + x^4\}$ a subset of $R_5[x]$ over $\mathbb R$ where $R_5[x]$ is the vector space of all polynomials with degree less than $5$.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

$R_5[x]$ has dimension 5, while your subset contains only 4 vectors.